# Advice for how to approach writing a custom control in Swift

Tags: ios, custom-controls

I am writing a custom control in Swift for an iPhone. I have mocked up a screenshot in Excel that I show something like what I want[image]

Each cell is a button or something. When the user selects the row with "Burger 2", the image changes to a burger, when the user selects the row with "Burger 3", the image changes to a different burger. A little "check" appears in the cell to indicate that, as shown in the mock-up, Burger 3/Mayo is selected, or Burger 2/Mayo is selected.

The user can only select one dressing of ketchup, mayo, BBQ Sauce or Chili Sauce. The image does not change when they select a different sauce or dressing.

I would like advice on how to approach the problem. If there is a custom control already from Apple or perhaps someone else, this would help me a lot too.

I have searched Github but do not find what I am looking for there.

Comment: My advice would be creating a table view with each row having a separate segmented control. With this way, you could add as many burger as you wanted, and you wouldn't need to deal with rows selected/deselected. Another option would be a collection view with multiple selection but with a customized selection control (remove ketchup/mayo/etc selection when bbq sauce/chili sauce/etc is selected for the same row). I'm writing this as a comment since the implementation would be too broad as an answer.

Comment: Consider that this kind of layout isn't a good fit for smaller screens. This is why UIPickerView exists.